# Redshift - Redesign tables to use DIST and SORT keys (performance issue)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm having serious performance problems on Redshift and I've started to rethink my tables structures.

Right now, I'm identifying tables that have most significance on my dashboard. First of all, I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM admin.v_extended_table_info
WHERE table_id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT s.tbl FROM stl_scan s
    JOIN pg_user u ON u.usesysid = s.userid
    WHERE s.type=2 AND u.usename='looker'
  )
ORDER BY SPLIT_PART("scans:rr:filt:sel:del",':',1)::int DESC,
  size DESC;
```

Based on query result, I could identify a lot of small tables (1-1000 records) that are distributed as `EVEN` and it could be `ALL` - this tables are used in a lot of joins instructions.

Beside that, I've identified that 99% of my tables are using `EVEN` without sort key. I'm not using denormalized tables so I need to run plenty of joins to get data - for what I've read, `EVEN` is not good for joins because it could be distributed over the network.

I have 3 tables related to Ticket flow: user, ticket and ticket_history. All those tables are `EVEN` without sort keys and diststyle as `EVEN`.

For now, I would like to redesign table `user`: this table is used on join by condition `ticket.user_id = user.id` and where clauses like `user.email = 'xxxx@xxxx.com'` or `user.email like '%@something.com%'` or `group by user.email`.

First thing I'm planning to do is use diststyle as distribution and key as `id`. Does make sense use a unique value as dist key? I've read plenty of posts about dist keys and still confuse for me.

As sort keys makes sense use email as compound? I've read to avoid columns that grows like dates, timestamps or identities, that's why i'm not using it as interleaved.  To avoid that `like`, I'm planning to create a new column to identify what is email domain.

After that, I'll change small tables to dist `ALL` and try my queries again.

Am I on right way? Any other tip?

This question could sound stupid but my tech background is only software development, I'm learning about Redshift and reading a lot of documentations.

Answer (score 2):

The basic rule of thumb is:

- Set the `DISTKEY` to the column that is most used in `JOINs`
- Set the `SORTKEY` to the column(s) most used in `WHEREs`

You are correct that small tables can have a distribution of `ALL`, which would avoid sending data between nodes.

`DISTKEY` provides the most benefit when tables are join via a common column that has the same `DISTKEY` in both tables. This means that each row is contained on the same node and no data needs to be sent between nodes (or, more accurately, slices). However, you can only select one `DISTKEY`, so do it on the column that is most often used for the `JOIN`.

`SORTKEY` provides the most benefit when Redshift can *skip over* blocks of storage. Each block of storage contains data for one column and is marked with a `MIN` and `MAX` value. When a table is sorted on a particular column, it minimises the number of disk blocks that contain data for a given column value (since they are all located together, rather than being spread randomly throughout disk storage). Thus, use column(s) that are most frequently used in `WHERE` statements.

If the `user.email` wildcard search is slow, you can certainly create a new column with the domain. Or, for even better performance, you could consider creating a separate lookup table with just `user_id` and `domain`, having `SORTKEY = domain`. This will perform the fastest when searching by domain.

**A tip from experience:** I would advise against using an email address as a `user_id` because people sometimes want to change email address. It is better to use a unique number for such `id` columns, with email address as a changeable attribute. (I've seen software systems need major rewrites to fix such an early design decision!)

Comment: And about use dist style as `KEY` instead of `EVEN` on tables that are used on JOINs? Makes sense?

Comment: `ALL` for small tables is great. `DISTKEY` with a specified `KEY` is great, as described above. That leaves `EVEN` for tables that are not the most-joined tables. It's sort of a "don't care" option. See also: [Amazon Redshift Best Practices for Designing Tables - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_designing-tables-best-practices.html)